# What SDK platforum is better to start learning with, 2.1 or 4.0.3?

Tags: android, sdk

I want to start programming for android devices and I have 1 question for you. I heard that Android is forward compatible. So, if I use 2.1, can I, at a later stage, update the app so it works with 4.0.3? What do you suggest me to do? Thank you for taking the time to answer these questions.

Comment: see my answer, android Ics 4.0 and upper deals with some hardware acceleration an User interface improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse always start with lower version `2.1`

Comment: Oh, thank you Parag. I will use '2.1'. But, I still have 1 question. What are the main differences, as for programming, between '2.1' and '4.0.3'?

Comment: Diff is that u will get more API In 4.0.3 than 2.1 here all details describe http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html

Comment: Okay. 1 question: Can a 2.2 app work on a 4.0.3 device? Not sure if that question makes any sense but you get the idea. :P

Comment: yes lower version always support to uper version but not vice versa

Answer (score 1):

2.1 is great for starters, but I would strongly advise to use [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) for learning and implementing Fragments since Fragment based apps are the general direction in which Android is heading.

Comment: Thank you, Medo. I will use that package. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start Android Development i would Advice you to learn some Java Basics First if you are not familiar with the java envirnment.

Concerning The Android Api that you should start with, I will advice you to start with the 2.2 Froyo it's one of the most stable Api.

The choice of the android platform depends also on the fact that developer want to target the Larger Number of devices that's why google provide a chart's, that show wich platform are the most used. you can find this chart in this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html).

Also in this [link](http://socialcompare.com/fr/comparison/android-versions-comparison) you can find the difference ore improvement on each platform, you can refer to the [android developer](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html) site to see differences

Comment: I see. Okay, I will download 2.2 SDK now and start using. Thank you.